# How to use AWS service for Mongodb and which service?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I just wanted to know, How can I use Mongodb service on AWS. I have seen there is no explicitly service to use Mongodb like for mysql it has RDS.

Any suggestions please...

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB is Amazons answer to managed NoSQL, the closest you get to MongoDB if you don't host it yourself (on an EC2 instance for example).

Answer (score 0):

MongoLab provides a MongoDB service on AWS. Or you can install MongoDB on an EC2 instance. Did you try searching for "MongoDB on AWS" at all?